Error adding phone number to WhatsApp API
I'm trying to create a simple ChatBot for WhatsApp and have hit a brick wall adding a phone number to the account. I've been Googling and trying various things for the last week and have gotten no further.
I have set up an App in my Facebook Developer account with WhatsApp; In API Setup I've added a new number (paid number that's guaranteed to work with WhatsApp, not one of the freebie ones), verified it by SMS and got an phone ID for that new number. However, when I try and 'generate access token', I get the following error:

If I try to register or verify the number via API, using either the  /PHONE_ID/register or /PHONE_ID/request_code endpoints, I get the same error message in the terminal saying the PHONE_ID does not exist, yet if do a check of /BUSINESS_ID/phone_numbers it returns a response with that very same PHONE_ID, eg:
{
   "data": [
      {
         "verified_name": "Business Name",
         "code_verification_status": "VERIFIED",
         "display_phone_number": "+44 XXXX XXXXX",
         "quality_rating": "UNKNOWN",
         "platform_type": "NOT_APPLICABLE",
         "throughput": {
            "level": "NOT_APPLICABLE"
         },
         "webhook_configuration": {
            "application": "https://foo.bar/mywebhook.php"
         },
         "id": "PHONE_ID"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "XXXXXX",
         "after": "XXXXX"
      }
   }
}

I have made sure the business itself is verified and has a payment source. The phone number name has been approved. I cannot find any unmissed alerts in WhatsApp manager, and yet the number remains 'pending'. In the API config, the drop-down shows the number, but is unselectable as it's saying it's not registered. Oh my days...
Any help would be much appreciated. I'm tearing my hair out over this one.

This seems like a customer support issue, not a programming issue, given this is a specific WhatsApp onboarding/config issue. Support questions are off-topic here - see Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

" I get the same error message in the terminal saying the PHONE_ID does not exist" The error you're showing us also states "cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or  does not support this operation." Don't assume the first reason it gives is the reason.

First of all if you have added the number from developer portal than you the number is registered already, u don't have to make register call or request OTP. You can simply generate a system access token. You will be able to use this token directly to send messages.
